# jQuery validate not reseting form to initial state from div selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validate and whilst it validates ok, what I am trying to is, if a user leaves the form, then reset it back to it's initial state. What is happening however, is on the click event, which I am specifying the form div as selector, it is removing the error messages but not removing the class on the inputs or the form. If however, I use the input id, this works ok.

Is there a way I can reset the form using the div selector as I have quite a few inputs to handle. Many thanks

Relevant jQuery snippet

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    errorClass: 'form_error2',
    //errorElement: 'span',
    //ignore: ":hidden:not(select)",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element);
   }
});

var validator = $("#addProfile").validate({
    rules: {
        companyName: {
            required: true
        },
        companyAddr1: {
            required: true
        },
        companyAddr3: {
            required: true
        },
        coProfTown: {
            required: true
        },
        coProfPostcode: {
            required: true
        }

    },
    messages: {
        companyName: {
            required: '* required: You must enter your name'
        },
        companyAddr1: {
            required: "* required: You must select a department"
        },
        companyAddr3: {
            required: "* required: You must select a service level"
        },
        coProfTown: {
            required: "* required: You must enter a box for retrieval"
        },
        coProfPostcode: {
            required: "* required: You must enter a box for retrieval"
        }
    },


$('#setHeaderRight').on('click', function() {
  $('#addProfile').removeClass("form_error2");
  validator.resetForm();
});
```

html

```
<div id="addProfileForm" style="display:none; margin-left:4px;">
    <form id="addProfile" name="addProfile" action="" method="post" class="webform">    
            <label for="companyName">Name:</label><br />
            <input id="companyName" name="companyName" type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all inputbox AC_item" placeholder="Enter Company name:" />

            <br />
            <label for="companyAddr1">Address1:</label><br />
            <input id="companyAddr1" name="companyAddr1" type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all inputbox AC_item" placeholder="Enter Company Address:" />

            <br />
            <label for="companyAddr2">Address2:</label><br />
            <input id="companyAddr2" name="companyAddr2" type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all inputbox AC_item" placeholder="Enter Company Address 2:" />

            <br />
            <label for="companyAddr3">Address3:</label><br />
            <input id="companyAddr3" name="companyAddr3" type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all inputbox AC_item" placeholder="Enter Company Address 3:" />

            <br />
            <label for="coProfTown">Town:</label><br />
            <input id="coProfTown" name="coProfTown" type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all inputbox AC_item" placeholder="Enter Town:" />

            <br />
            <label for="coProfPostcode">Postcode:</label><br />
            <input id="coProfPostcode" name="coProfPostcode" type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all inputbox AC_item" placeholder="Enter Postcode:" />
            <br />

            <p>
            <input name="submit" class="addprofilesubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </p>
    </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: did you try: `$('.className').removeClass('className')` ?

Comment: What do you mean by *" if a user leaves the form"*..? How will the user leave the form..?

Comment: In other words, cancels the submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have a syntax error.  You forgot to properly close the `.validate()` method...

```
var validator = $("#addProfile").validate({
    rules: {
        // ...
    },
    messages: {
        // ...
    },
});  // <- CLOSING BRACKETS WERE MISSING


$('#setHeaderRight').on('click', function () {
    // $('#addProfile').removeClass("form_error2"); // not needed
    validator.resetForm();
});
```

Your code appears to be working as designed...

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/61u66zdj/1/**

---

Otherwise, create a jsFiddle demo of the broken behavior and submit it to the developer [here at his GitHub page](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation).  Meanwhile, since this seems to be a bug you're reporting, there isn't really anything else we can do for you here.

Comment: Thank you Sparky. Much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
jQuery("#addProfile")[0].reset();
```

or without jQuery

```
document.getElementById("addProfile").reset();
```

Comment: That's not what he's asking.  He is trying to implement the `.resetForm()` method as provided by the plugin.  See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.resetForm/